# HttpClient not performing under heavy load

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have serious problems with the .NET `HttpClient` under heavy load. I have created a GitHub repo to demonstrate the problem. Would greatly appreciate any help. Yes, I am only using one `HttpClient` per authority. Same problem with http and https. Not a server-side problem, as server maintains responsive the whole time.

https://github.com/erikbra/HttpClientProblems/issues/1

Typically get the following error. `System.Net` trace log says it's calling `::Abort` on the connection. But very difficult to get any more info.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at UnitTests.Call_Api.<CallApi>d__22.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\HttpClientProblems\UnitTests.NetCore\Call_Api.cs:line 204
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at UnitTests.Call_Api.<Measure>d__23.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ErikBrandstadmoen\Source\Repos\HttpClientProblems\UnitTests.NetCore\Call_Api.cs:line 219
```

[UPDATE]

To be precise, I want to understand what is happening. Obviously the connection is being cut of, but why? The server is still responding, so it's not a limitation on the server side. Where is the bottleneck?

What happens if I e.g. set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to 2, and start 4 tasks? Won't they be served in turn? Similar with, say, 128 and 1000. But somewhere it stops scaling. How can I investigate further what the bottleneck is? I only get a `TaskCanceledException`, and those carry no more detail. Any tips?

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this post after 2 years but did you ever find a solution? I'm seeing the same behavior. Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't looked at this for a couple of years, so I can't recall. But, I would definitely recomment using IHttpClientFactory now. It works in .net 4.x too, if you use DI into your controllers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

I didn't go into code details of your github solution but this smells as an expected behavior. There is a setting of maximum connection numbers per `ServicePoint` and its normal that you run out of connections quicker on longer running requests when you do parallel, async execution.

This might be a good starting point:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/managing-connections

There is no definite, unified answer about how many connections is ok but you should keep your `MaxDegreeOfParalelism` below the number of your maximum connections allowed and you're safe.

**[UPDATE]**

Also, what you might want to take a look at is `System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.winhttphandler(v=vs.105).aspx

When you make an instance of `HttpClient`, you can do something like this:

```
var httpMessageHandler = new System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler();
//here you set different handler options (see docs link above)
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpMessageHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will look into the WinHttpHandler. But, thinking of it, isn't this a problem with how HttpClient assigns messages to the HttpConnections? If I run all requests in series, it obviously succeeds, albeit slow. Then it is using only 1 connection. Shouldn't HttpClient handle this nicely, so that all tasks sending RequestMessages are nicely queued up, and assigned to the number of available HttpConnections? So, if I had 2 connections, it should finish in half the time, if using 16, 1/16th of the time, etc? I can see the messages getting assigned to connections if Tracing.

Comment: exactly, but how would httpclient know the number of available connections if you dont tell it? you can run http client requests on windows home with 4 or 10 connections max or on server with 10000 connections max. and they will start reporting problems on different treshholds.

Answer (score 0):

More accurately, it's the HttpMessageHandler that is being used by the HttpClient that is underperforming.

I have backported the .NET Core 2.1 SocketsHttpHandler to .NET Framework and I observed significant performance improvements with the [backported implementation](https://github.com/TalAloni/StandardSocketsHttpHandler) compared to .NET Framework HttpClientHandler when dozens of multiple requests are issued concurrently.